# how add records to a partitioned delta table?

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I am practicing with the partitioning of a table, I have this

```
df.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").partitionBy("Month").save(path)
```

But I'm not sure how add records, maybe something like this

```
df2.write.format("delta").mode("append").partitionBy("Month").save(path)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you just need to append new records, you need to use `append` mode instead of `overwrite`. In future, when you will need to update some records & insert other, then you need to look onto [MERGE INTO command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/delta/delta-update#--upsert-into-a-table-using-merge).